# String slicing: ending index specification as -1 seems to be wrong

Tags: python-3.x, string

If there is a string initialized in python:

```
s="SLICE"
```

When trying to run this code:

```
print(s[4::-1])    #Line-1
print(s[4:-1:-1])   #Line2
```

I thought both are the same thing and give the same output. Instead, Line 1 outputs as expected but Line 2 does not.

Comment: This is not specified anywhere. How could it be a duplicate question?

Comment: I nominated this question for reopening. If it's reopened I'll post an answer.

Comment: [As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/567094/3345375), slice notation is `s[from:to:step]`. And in a five-character string such as `"SLICE"`, the fifth character `s[4]` is also the last character `s[-1]`. Thus, `s[4]` through `s[-1]` is an empty string, and `s[4:-1:x]` is an empty string for any value of x.

Comment: To iterate backwards through the whole string, use this: `s[-1:-6:-1]`. Its starting character is s[-1]. Its ending character is s[-5], which is one step before s[-6] when iterating backwards through the string. Thus, the slice includes the last character through the fifth-to-last character; in other words, the entire five-character string in reverse order.

Comment: And as I said, we'll see if the question is reopened. I don't think it's a duplicate.